# How to make subdirectory the document root of a web domain or localhost

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a subdirectory `abc` in the document root `/var/www/html`

I want to be able to run any file `any_file.html` within the subdirectory by typing in the browser:

`localhost/any_file` instead of `localhost/abc/any_file.html` or
`my_domain.com/any_file` instead of `my_domain.com/abc/any_file.html`

I tried writing in `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/abc">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html
</Directory>
```

But it doesn't work. `Options FollowSymLinks` is activated in `<Directory>` so I believe I would not need to write this again. Does anyone knows why and how to solve it? Thanks.

**Update:** I have another subdirectory `efg` which I need to be able to access through localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring the Vhost for the domain, you need to add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
     <Directory />
          *your options*
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now your `/` will be `/var/www/html/abc`

If your document structure is like this:

```
/
-abc
-edf
```

You will now by default access the abc folder. If you also want to access the edf folder you have two options:

- Make another vhost for a subdomain who's documentroot is edf
- Symlink the edf folder into abc

Symlinking is pretty straightforward (ln command). To make another vhost you can create a new file in your `sites-available/` folder or add these entries at the bottom of your `sites-available/default`

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/efg
ServerName efg.mydomain.com

if you made a new file you need to run:

```
a2ensite filename
```

and restart apache.
Now when you visit the subdomain (don't forget it to add it to your dns server). It will use efg as it's documentroot.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I am testing it on my development server. The production server will be a dedicated server. Can I still implement your solution? I don't quite understand why document root is `/var/www`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I made a mistake sorry. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) from

```
/var/www/html
```

to

```
/var/www/html/abc
```

Comment: Thanks lain, I have thought about that, but I would like to be able to access to another subdirectory `efg` too.

Comment: We're not mind readers - If you don't provide all of the relevant information then we can't be expected to give you the correct answer. You have 3 answers that all say the same thing, this is because we all answered the question as asked.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the directive

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

to be

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
```

in the corresponding virtual host.

Another option is to use mod-rewrite to rewrite every path that starts with `/abc` to be without it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second option? I would like to try that. Thanks.